# Powershell: Can it be kept loaded to make script loading faster?

Tags: powershell

This is on Win10 and Win11:

I find that a desktop shortcut that runs:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\develop\utils\fetchlatest.ps1
```

Takes about 3 seconds to even start executing.

Is there a way I can cut this down?

Comment: [`-NoProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-noprofile) maybe

Comment: If you are needing immediate response, you will almost have to keep the program running in a loop with it waiting for user interaction such as pressing the enter key.  If you don't have an SSD, then upgrading that might help - but I'm not sure how much it would help.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Tried that. Little or no difference in performance.

Comment: @Darin Excellent thought. I have passed that thought into this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/71014273/147637