# Powershell: Can Register-ObjectEvent watch for clipboard events?

Tags: powershell

(On Windows 10 and 11)

I have successfully used Register-ObjectEvent to watch for file system events.

Can it also be used to watch for clipboard events?

In other words, how is Register-ObjectEvent used to hook Clipboard.ContentChanged [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.contentchanged?view=winrt-22000) ?  (Or an equivalent event)

If so, is there an example somewhere? (I looked around but did not spot)

If not, what would the method be to monitor the clipboard?

I've been digging through the MS documentation, and can't find the way to do this (via Register-ObjectEvent or any other method).

Specifically, I want to be notified when a new text object appears on the clipboard. (I would then read the text, and parse it to see if it contained an element of interest, and if so, do some processing.)

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.contentchanged

Comment: @stackprotector Thanks! That is a WinRT API. It is unclear to me how to exploit it from powershell. Where to look next?

Comment: This works: https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/cpowershell-clipboard-watcher/

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks! That is BY FAR the closest thing I have seen on this topic. HOWEVER that code is several years old and does not run natively on Win11. I get this error: " Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.. 
Verify that Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5  is installed. On x64-based versions of Windows, you must also install 
the WOW64 feature."

Comment: @JosefZ OK, I got it working. I'll post a link to it once I get it up on github in the next day or two. THANKS!

Comment: @JosefZ OK, usable script is not visible. See the answer I posted below. Thanks a TON for the pointer!

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry, should say: usable script is NOW visible.  https://github.com/samjones3/powershell-utilities/blob/main/PowerShell-Clipboard-Watcher.ps1

Answer (score 1):

OK, there appears to be no direct way to do this.

What I had hoped was that there was the right kind of object surfaced to Register-ObjectEvent that would make this a direct implementation. Something like IO.ClipBoardWatcher version of [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0). But it appears there is no such animal.

The solution on [mnaoumov.NET](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/cpowershell-clipboard-watcher/) was proposed. It looked right, but on Win11 it does not run as is. (It is 7+ years old at this point.)

I made a few tweaks to it, and have it running on Win11 (and I expect it will also run fine on Win10). This mod can be found [here](https://github.com/samjones3/powershell-utilities/blob/main/PowerShell-Clipboard-Watcher.ps1).

The overall approach is that a piece of C# is injected to hook the ClipboardTextChanged event from the .NET/Win32 world. That is then monitored by the Powershell Register-ObjectEvent engine.

If there is a more direct, more Powershell-native way to do this, would love to see it!