# Don't Understand what this code is supposed to do?

Tags: powershell

I copied this code from the internet and was reviewing it for possible upgrading. However, I can't for the life of me figure what the last 2 lines of this snip are supposed to accomplish. In fact I can delete them from a running program I use the code in and the program continues to function normally. I would normally just assume it was leftover junk that didn't get deleted but I found the same last 4 lines of code in another program.

```
#------------------- Add ClipBoard Watcher Code --------------
# This script is a small update to the one found here:
# https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/cpowershell-clipboard-watcher/

# This started in this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71014273/147637
# This is expected to run fine on Win10 and Win11 (and probably other versions)

# This script binds the OS functions to monitor when new items are put on the clipboard.
# It is a powershell script, that has been tested to work. 

$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
function PSScriptRoot { $MyInvocation.ScriptName | Split-Path }
Trap { throw $_ }
```

Note: I searched the program for references to PsScriptRoot and they don't exist except for the name of this function which is never called.

Comment: Seeing as it's a function, is it getting called? My guess is as good as yours - *left over junk*. `PSScriptRoot` will return just the path of the ps1 that was just called on; well, it's parent directory. Maybe it was used for some other function? As far as `Trap { }` goes, that's just a means of error handling terminating errors. T'was before `try{}catch{}` was introduced. Would take it as junk if neither are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`
>
> `Trap { throw $_ }`

**The [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement is *redundant***, because setting the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) to `Stop` *by itself* has the effect of promoting both non-terminating and statement-terminating errors to *script*-terminating (fatal) errors.

> `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`

**In *production* code, it is ill-advised to use `-Version Latest` with [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)**, because the code may break in *future* PowerShell versions should they include additional strictness checks that your code then could fail.

> `function PSScriptRoot { $MyInvocation.ScriptName | Split-Path }`

**Without this function definition ever getting *called*, it amounts to *dead weight***, as [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) points out.

As an aside: While the function's name suggests that it's trying to duplicate the value of the [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) (for which there is no good reasons, since the variable has been available since v2), it returns something *different*: `$MyInvocation.ScriptName` contains the path of the *calling* script, if any, *not* that of the *running* script.

Comment: Exactly what I thought but you never know what unknown quirks and tricks a programmer is using so I thought I'd ask just to make sure.